# How to input a formular for this particular situation, I Have No Idea how to do this

Tags: excel

Okay this is going to be kinda hard to explain without the aid of a screenshot, but here it goes:

I have a table featuring match-ups between animals on the food chain, with HAWK, SNAKE, MOUSE, and INSECT as both my row and column headers (in the same order, from HAWK to INSECT).

B1 **| HAWK | SNAKE | MOUSE | INSECT |** (COLUMN HEADERS)

A2 **HAWK** | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

A3 **SNAKE** |1/2| 1 | 2 | 2 |

A4 **MOUSE** | 0 |1/2| 1 | 2 |

A5 **INSECT** | 0 | 0 |1/2| 1 |

Now the values given are arbitrary, but basically, a match-up where the first animal eats the second is given a 2, a match-up that features the same animal is given a 1, a match-up where the second animal can fight back against the first is given a 1/2, and a match-up where the second animal is completely vulnerable to the first is given a 0.

In the first row, I gave a 1 for HAWK vs HAWK, and a 2 for HAWK vs SNAKE, HAWK vs MOUSE and HAWK vs INSECT. So it would look like this: |1|2|2|2|

In the second row, I gave a 1/2 for SNAKE vs HAWK, a 1 for SNAKE vs SNAKE, and a 2 for SNAKE vs MOUSE and SNAKE vs INSECT. So it would look like this: |1/2|1|2|2|

In the third row, I gave a 0 for MOUSE vs HAWK, a 1/2 for MOUSE vs SNAKE, a 1 for MOUSE vs MOUSE, and a 2 for MOUSE vs INSECT. So it would look like this: |0|1/2|1|2|

Finally, in the fourth row, I gave a 0 for INSECT vs HAWK and INSECT vs SNAKE, a 1/2 for INSECT vs MOUSE, and a 1 for INSECT vs INSECT. So it would look like this: |0|0|1/2|1|

Then I made another table that counted the number of these values for each animal, so for instance the HAWK has three 2s and one 1, the SNAKE has two 2s, one 1, and one 1/2...etc. I did this so that I could eventually come up with a final score for each animal:

B7 **| 2 | 1 |1/2| 0 |** (COLUMN HEADERS)

A8 **HAWK** | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

A9 **SNAKE** | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |

A10 **MOUSE** | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

A11 **INSECT** | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |

I then multiplied each of these values by a multiplier (so any value under the column "2" was multiplied by 2, any value under "1" would be multiplied by 1, any value under "1/2" would be multiplied by -0.5, and any value under "0" would by multiplied by -1):

B7 **| 2 | 1 |1/2| 0 |** (COLUMN HEADERS)

A2 **HAWK** | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |**>>| 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 |**

A3 **SNAKE** | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |**>>| 4 | 1 |-0.5| 0 |**

A4 **MOUSE** | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |**>>| 2 | 1 |-0.5|-1 |**

A5 **INSECT** | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |**>>| 0 | 1 |-0.5|-2 |**

Lastly, I added the numbers and gave each animal an **initial score**:

B7 ** | 2 | 1 |1/2| 0 |** (COLUMN HEADERS)

A2 **HAWK** | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 |>>| 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | **7.0 |**

A3 **SNAKE** | 2 | 1 | 1 | 0 |>>| 4 | 1 |-0.5| 0 | **4.5 |**

A4 **MOUSE** | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |>>| 2 | 1 |-0.5|-1 | **1.5 |**

A5 **INSECT** | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 |>>| 0 | 1 |-0.5|-2 | **-1.5 |**

In my final table, I want to quantify how "defensive" each animal is (based on these values):

B13 **| 0 |1/2| 1 | 2 |** (COLUMN HEADERS)

A14 **HAWK** |   |   |   |   |

A15 **SNAKE** |   |   |   |   |

A16 **MOUSE** |   |   |   |   |

A17 **INSECT** |   |   |   |   |

Here, the "0" (first column) represents how many immunities each animal has, the "1/2" (second column) represents how many resistances each animals has, the "1" (third column) represents each neutrality, while the "2" (fourth column) represents how many vulnerabilities each has.

If we look at the MOUSE specifically, we need to count how many of these characteristics it has (immunities, resistances, vulnerabilities...etc.)

We do this by looking back at the first table and counting how many "0" (immunities) the MOUSE has. If you go down the MOUSE column, you find that there are none.

Now we go down the column again and count how many "1/2" (resistances) the MOUSE has. It resists the INSECT, so it has one.

We then go down and count how many "1" (neutralities) the MOUSE has. By default it has one, itself.

Finally, we go down and count how many "2" (vulnerabilities) it has. The MOUSE is vulnerable to both the SNAKE and the HAWK, so it has two.

Now the difference here is to substitute the value for the **initial score** and add them up in each column. So the row for the MOUSE would look like this:

B13 **| 0 |1/2| 1 | 2 |** (COLUMN HEADERS)

A14 **HAWK** |   |   |   |   |

A15 **SNAKE** |   |   |   |   |

A16 **MOUSE**  **| 0 |-1.5| 1.5|11.5 (7.0+4.5)|**

A17 **INSECT** |   |   |   |   |

I am basically asking four questions for each animals:

How many **total** points does a(n) *(insert animal here)* ***_*__*_*__** have in terms of immunities?

How many **total** points does a(n) *(insert animal here)* ***_*__*_*__** have in terms of resistances?

How many **total** points does a(n) *(insert animal here)* ***_*__*_*__** have in terms of neutralities?

How many **total** points does a(n) *(insert animal here)* ***_*__*_*__** have in terms of vulnerabilities?

My question is what formula would I need to input into each box so that the total number of points **(initial score)** corresponding to each characteristic appears?

The main reason for having a formula is that if I decided to change the values in the first table, then everything would update without me having to update the scores manually.

I have a feeling this may require the VLOOKUP function, but I wouldn't know how to go about it.

Hope this isn't too confusing, ask if you need clarification on anything and I'll try my best to do so.

Thanks to anyone who understands this particular problem and bothers to solve it :P

Comment: Welcome! Many looking at this question will dismiss it as TL;DR. You can probably frame the question with 30% or less words.

Comment: If I could insert an image or screenshot, I wouldn't need to write so much, but because I can't I have to try and explain the problem I have in as much detail so people can understand it better.

Comment: @PAO3092 You can insert a link to a picture (upload to an image hosting site or something). That still works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A2 HAWK | 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 |

A3 SNAKE |1/2| 1 | 2 | 2 |

A4 MOUSE | 0 |1/2| 1 | 2 |

A5 INSECT | 0 | 0 |1/2| 1 |

>>

*=COUNTIF($B2:$E2 ,"=2") 
means count the number of cells from B2 until E2 which have the value 2*

A6 HAWK | =COUNTIF($B2:$E2 ,"=2") | =COUNTIF($B2:$E2 ,"=1") | =COUNTIF($B2:$E2 ,"=0.5") | =COUNTIF($B2:$E2 ,"=0") |

A7 SNAKE |=COUNTIF($B3:$E3 ,"=2")| ...

A8 MOUSE | ...

A9 INSECT | ...

>>

A11 HAWK | =B6*2 | =C6*1 | =D6*-0.5 | =E6*-1 |

A12 SNAKE |=B7*2| ...

A13 MOUSE | ...

A14 INSECT | ...

>>

A11 HAWK | =B6*2 | =C6*1 | =D6*-0.5 | =E6*-1 | =SUM(B11:E11)

A12 SNAKE |=B7*2| ...                        | =SUM(B12:E12)

A13 MOUSE | ...

A14 INSECT | ...

>>

*=COUNTIF(B$2:B$5 ,"=0") 
means count the number of cells from B2 until B5 which have the value 0*

A16 HAWK | =COUNTIF(B$2:B$5 ,"=0") | =COUNTIF(B$2:B$5 ,"=0.5") | =COUNTIF(B$2:B$5 ,"=1") | =COUNTIF(B$2:B$5 ,"=2") |

A17 SNAKE |=COUNTIF(C$2:C$5 ,"=0")| ...

A18 MOUSE | ...

A19 INSECT | ...

>>

*=SUMIF($B$2:$B$5 ,"=0",$F$11:$F$14) 
means it sums all cells from F11 to F14 where the corresponding cell in B2 until B5 has the value 0*

A21 HAWK | =SUMIF($B$2:$B$5 ,"=0",$F$11:$F$14) | =SUMIF($B$2:$B$5 ,"=0.5",$F$11:$F$14) | =SUMIF($B$2:$B$5 ,"=1",$F$11:$F$14) | =SUMIF($B$2:$B$5 ,"=2",$F$11:$F$14) |

A22 SNAKE | =SUMIF($C$2:$C$5 ,"=0",$F$11:$F$14) | ...

A23 MOUSE | ...

A24 INSECT | ...

edit: added descriptions

Comment: Wow you are a genius, I used the formula and it gave me the values I was looking for. I don't know how you did it, but you did! I know it must have been kinda daunting to have seen a wall of text with a somewhat confusing layout, so I appreciate the fact that you even bothered to read the question. Again thank you :P